# Infinite setInterval even though it should've cleared?

Tags: javascript, canvas, setinterval

How come that the setInterval doesn't clear it self?... with each loop  `globalAlpha` is 0.1 more. Yet even though it stops incrementing at 1. The loop just keeps going??

MY full code at, this is at the bottom of the file: https://github.com/GunZi200/Memory-Colour/blob/master/test.js

```
function secondCanvasFirst(){
    //if (collides(secondCanvas, exx, eyy)) {
    console.log("true");
    var j = 0, 
    i = setInterval(function () {
        context.globalAlpha = j;
        context.fillStyle = '#F8F8FF';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, x, y);
        j += 0.1;
        console.log(context.globalAlpha);
        if (context.globalAlpha.toFixed(0) === 1) {
            clearInterval(i);
            userTurn = true;
            b_canvas.addEventListener('click', clickEvent, false);
            alert("hi");
            second = true;
            game_interface();
        }
    }, 100);
}
        var clickEvent1 = function clickEvent1(e) {
            new FastClick.attach(document.body);
            console.log("clickevent1");
            exx = e.offsetX;
            eyy = e.offsetY;
            secondCanvasFirst();
        }

        if (b_canvas && b_canvas.getContext) {
            b_canvas.addEventListener('click', clickEvent1, false);
            FastClick.attach(document.body);
        }
```

Comment: How abou `var i` instead if just `i`?

Comment: Try to use setTimeout instead of setInterval. You have more control over it.

Comment: @David, thank you so much. Don't really see how that would have changed anything, but it did.

Comment: setTimeout will only run once - I doubt it's what you want

Comment: @GuðniMárGilbert, I just put a vague explanation in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, essentially when you have:

```
i = setInterval(function () {
```

`i` is undefined. As in, it doesn't even exist. So when you get to this part

```
clearInterval(i);
```

It says, `i`? What's that? Now I think JS has some capability to where it would derive that `i` is a variable, but I'm guessing that because you're passing it into another inner function, that that is where the issue comes into play.

So

```
var i = setInterval(function () {
```

should solve your problem

Comment: `i` *is* actually defined (unless OP managed to update the posted code within the first 5 mins)... It's a comma-separated `var` list. If you look closely you can see: var j = 0 **,** i = ... etc. (in any case, `i` would end up on the window object if not).

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg, I see that now. Strange though because he said that that worked in the comments.

Comment: Yeah, that is kind of strange, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

try replacing

```
context.globalAlpha.toFixed(0) === 1
```

with

```
context.globalAlpha > 0.95
```

toFixed converts your value to a String, which is not what you want.